# How I calculate the time complexity of this sorting function?

Tags: c++

this is sorting function and i want that how would i calculate its time complexity?
I tried it but confused?

```
void sort()
{
    initilaization();

    for(i = 0; i < userSize - 1; i++)
    {
       for(int j = i+1; j < userSize; j++)
       {
          if(array[i] > array[j])
           {
              int t = array[i];
              array[i] = array[j];
              array[j] = t;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `O(n^2)`. Each loop does `n-c` calculations, where `c` is some constant, and `n` is the length of the container.

Comment: This is just Selection Sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: how would i explained O(n2), for one (for loop) we have O(n) and for other one we have [ O(n) ] so how it become O(n2).
if i am not wrong is it as that O(n*n). beacuse we use nested for loops.

Comment: Not sure that your function works BTW, final a[0] might only be original `a[0]` or `a[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two for loops, and they do n+... +3+2+1 comparisons. That's O(n2).

Comment: would you explain it please? that how?

Comment: The arithmetic sum, for 1 to n, is n*(n+1)/2. In terms of complexity, that's n squared.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of this in terms of the summation formula for natural numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation

To sum all the integers from 1 to a certain N you can do:

```
Sum = (n * (n + 1)) / 2
```

Now if you look at your nested loop that's exactly what you are doing. First inner iteration is N times. Then N - 1 until it's only 1 left for the very last one.

If you multiply out the above formula you get:

```
(n^2) / 2 + n/2
```

which leads to `O(n^2)`.